# Xero API Oauth / API Calls From a Subdomain

Tags: oauth, xero-api

Due to changes in my company we need to use 2 servers for handling the Oauth process of our Partner Xero integration.

I would love to know if there are any restrictions for going through the Oauth process / making API calls from a domain different then the domain in my Xero app configuration? 
i.e - If my app's domain is mydomain.com and the oauth process is completed via xxx.mydomain.com. And API calls will be made from xxx.mydomain.com as well.

Also, if I have servers on 2 different sub domains: xx.mydomain.com and yy.mydomain.com, Do i need to use 2 different server certificates? Can i use the same certificate for both servers?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same certificate for multiple apps.

There are no restrictions on the location from which you can make API requests. You just need to make sure that, if you're specifying a callback url in your initial call to get a request token, the domain of your callback url matches one you've saved for the app on https://developer.xero.com/myapps/